# jQuery AJAX request fail after second try (NO HEADERS FOR THIS REQUEST)

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, yii2, upload

I'm developing an app in Yii2 framework (basic), and I use jQuery AJAX call to upload a file.
First try works fine, as expected, but when I try to upload another file (without refreshing the page) the request fail.

I tried also to include headers. My piece of code looks like this (nevermind the PHP variables and comments):

```
var file = $("#attachment-file'.$hw->id.'").val().substr($("#attachment-file'.$hw->id.'").val().lastIndexOf("fakepath") + 9);
                    $("#AttachmentFileId'.$hw->id.'").html(file);
                    
                    var file_data = $("#attachment-file'.$hw->id.'").prop("files")[0];
                    var form_data = new FormData();
                    form_data.append("attachment-file'.$hw->id.'", file_data);
                    
                    // alert(form_data);
                    
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "'.Url::to(['site/upload-hw', 'codeId' => $attachment->code_id, 'lessionId' => $lession->id, 'hwId' => $hw->id]).'",
                        // dataType: "text",
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        // contentType: "multipart/form-data",
                        processData: false,
                        headers: { 
                            // "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                            "X-Requested-With" : "XMLHttpRequest",
                            // "Accept" : "text/plain"  
                        }, 
                        data: form_data,
                        method: "POST",
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function (response) {
                            $("#AttachmentFileId'.$hw->id.'").html(response); 
                            $("#AttachmentFileId'.$hw->id.'").fadeIn(); 
                            $("#AttachmentFileId'.$hw->id.'").fadeOut(7000); 
                            $("#AttachmentFileId'.$hw->id.'").html("");
                            $("#AttachmentFileId'.$hw->id.'").fadeIn(); 
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            $("#AttachmentFileId'.$hw->id.'").html(response);
                        }
                    }); return false;
```

Does anyone know why is this happening?
Thank you.
Luka